# How to direct include Vue.js <script> in Magento 2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, magento2

I want to use Vue.js in Magento 2 by the **[Direct  Include](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Direct-lt-script-gt-Include)** , but, for some reason, the script doesn't call the content and then, the local Vue script doesn't work.

[image: ReferenceError: Vue is not defined]

I put the CDN in the header with the others
[image: Scripts and stylesheets in Content > Configuration > Edit Theme > HTML Head]

And is here in the page "loaded"
[image: Ricght click in the page > Code font page]

The HTML and Vue content works in codepen and others platforms

```js
var gobantesCatalogos = new Vue({
  el: '#catalogs',
  data: {
    urlComun: '/pub/media/wysiwyg/catalogo/',
    items: [
      { titulo: 'File1', nombreArchivo: 'FileName1', nombreImagen: 'img1' },
      { titulo: 'File2', nombreArchivo: 'FileName2', nombreImagen: 'img2' },
      { titulo: 'File3', nombreArchivo: 'FileName3', nombreImagen: 'img3' },
      { titulo: 'File4', nombreArchivo: 'FileName4', nombreImagen: 'img4' },
      { titulo: 'File5', nombreArchivo: 'FileName5', nombreImagen: 'img5' },
      { titulo: 'File6', nombreArchivo: 'FileName6', nombreImagen: 'img6' }
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<h1>Catalogue</h1>
<div id="catalogs" class="columnss">
    <div class="column-lg-3 column-md-4 column-xs-6" v-for="(item, index) in items">
        <a v-bind:href="urlComun + item.nombreArchivo" class="catalogue" target="_blank" :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + urlComun + item.nombreImagen + ')' }">
            <div class="fondo">
                <h2 class="titulo">{{ item.titulo }}</h2>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

But, doesn't work in the page. Anyone has tried to use Vue.js in Magento 2 without PWA Vue Storefront?
What did I miss?

Thanks you for read it,